# AJAX post request success callback to create div element

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, http-post

I'm trying to make a POST request to a fake database by passing data received from GitHub.

On the "success" callback for my POST request, I want to create a '' element, in which will include my github avatar photo, username, and name.

So far my code has the GET request to github API and POST request to the fake database(I think), but I'm not sure I'm using a callback function correctly to create the div element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://fakedatabase.com", 
  success: function(callback){
    $('<div />', { id: 'divOne'}).append(callback);
  }
});

var ghlink = 'http://api.github.com/users/MYUSERNAME';
 $.get(ghlink, function(response_data) {
  console.log(response_data);
 });  
});
```

Am I on the right track? This is my first time dabbling in AJAX requests and I'm feeling a bit lost.

Comment: Assuming that `callback` is raw string (and not JSON or some other structured data), this might do: `$('<div />', { id: 'divOne'}).html(callback).appendTo('body');` or `appendTo('anotherSelector');`

Comment: caution, it's `success: function(data){}` - the anonymous function already is a callback function which returns the response of your request in the `data` variable in my example.

Comment: What about this isn't working?

Comment: @low_rents so I can't use the "callback" variable? I have to use data? I didnt know the anonymous function was already a callback function

Comment: @haim770 I don't believe callback is JSON or other structured data. It's just a word I am using to remind myself its a callback function.

Comment: @brianchangdev you can use the "callback" variable. but i just wanted to point out that it's not a callback-function saved in this variable called "callback". the response-data is saved there just like in your `response_data` variable. so better don't call it "callback" since it will confuse you.